# Remove "[ ]" from excerpt in highlight search term

Tags: excerpt

I am using highlight search terms in my wordpress website. In my search result, the last character of the excerpt is as below:

> This is the excerpt.[...]

I have the code in my **functions.php** which i got from Stackexchange.

```
function search_excerpt_highlight() {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $excerpt = preg_replace(
        '/(' . $keys .')/iu',
        '<span class="search-highlight"><u>\0</u></span>',
        $excerpt
        ) 
        . "<br/><div class='right'><a href='" 
        . get_permalink($post->ID) 
        . " '>Read more...</a></div>";
    echo '' . $excerpt . '';
}

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 25;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

How do i remove the "[ ]" in the excerpt and make it to "..." only? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`excerpt_more`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) filter:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpse174028_change_excerpt_more' );
function wpse174028_change_excerpt_more( $excerpt_more ) {
    return '...';
}
```

Comment: My pleasure! Easy, if you already know what to do. @Jornes

Comment: Alright. I'm still new in wordpress. There are lots to ask and learn. Thanks again! @ialocin :)